# can you use mods on scalacube?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I want to play on a server with me and my friend.

Can you use mods on [ScalaCube](https://scalacube.com/hosting/server/minecraft?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=search_america&utm_content=text1&utm_term=%2Bminecraft%20%2Bbuy%20%2Bserver&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI4Yih3pzj2AIVlUoNCh3uzwGvEAAYASAAEgKqIPD_BwE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, depending on what you choose on the hosting site you provided (ScalaCube).

According to the hosting site, it provides Modpack Support. It also provides instant server setups for 230 modpacks.